# Sanitizing user input when creating HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss

I am trying to make a to-do application in pure HTML5 and Javascript and I have come across the problem of sanitizing the input.

For eg: If user enters `<script>alert("XSS")</script>`, the code is executed on the page.

Code for adding an element is:

```
if ($('#TextArea').val() !== "") {
  var taskID = new Date().getTime();
  var taskMessage = $('#textArea').val();
  localStorage.setItem(taskID, taskMessage);
}
```

while the code for displaying the elements is:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = localStorage.length; i != 0; i--) {
  var taskID = localStorage.key(i - 1);
  $('#task').append("<li id='" + taskID + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(taskID) + "</li>");
}
```

Is there any way to sanitize the data using only HTML5 and Javascript properties?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637275/simple-html-sanitizer-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with any and all XSS prevention: Don't build HTML from strings, *especially not* when those strings contain user-supplied values.

jQuery has [a convenient facility to build elements safely](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) - you can pass in an object with properties:

```
$("<li>", {
  id: taskID,
  text: localStorage.getItem(taskID)
}).appendTo('#task');
```

In fact, I recommend that you absolutely never use string concatenation to build HTML. For more complex situations than the above, use a well-tested HTML templating library like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Sir, if I have to insert an anchor tag, such that `<a href="something"><li>something</li></a>` , then how should I go on with that?

Comment: You can't nest an `<li>` inside an `<a>`, so let's do it the other way around: `$("<li>").append( $("<a>", {href: "something", text: "something"}) );`. This gets tedious very fast, that's why I recommended a templating engine. Compare a few and pick up one you like.

Comment: But sir, if I have to use the above code: `$("<li>", {id: taskID,text:localStorage.getItem(taskID)}).appendTo('#task');` with `$("<li>").append( $("<a>", {href: "something", text: "something"}) );`, how can we do so?

Comment: `$("<li>").append( $("<a>", {href: "something", text: "something"}) ).appendTo("#task");`, if I understand you right. Itr seems like you are missing essential jQuery basics, please take some time to learn how jQuery works. It's not a good idea to use a library that you don't really understand.

Comment: No sir, I understood that part. Actually, if you will see this: https://jsfiddle.net/bwk54ma2/1/ . What I am unable to do is that, I also want <li> to have id=taskID (such that `<li id=taskID><a href=taskID>Something</a></li>`), and I can't nest that property.